# how call main form method inside another form using C#?

Tags: c#

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String Path1 = Application.StartupPath + "\\component.xml";
    XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    XmlDocument dom;
    TreeNode tNode;
    const int NORM_UI = 0;
    const int SELECTED_UI = 1;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.treeview();
    }

  public void treeview()
    {
        try
        {

            dom = new XmlDocument();
            dom.Load(Path1);


            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(dom.DocumentElement.Name));
            tNode = new TreeNode();
            tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
            tNode.ForeColor = Color.Blue;



            AddNode(dom.DocumentElement, tNode, NORM_UI, -1);
        }
        catch (XmlException xmlEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

i want to call this treeview () method when button 2 click in following form please help me

```
 public partial class TabPageEntry_Form2 : Form
{
    public TabPageEntry_Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `treeview()` is an instance method so you need to create an object of Form1

```
Form1 frm=new Form1();
frm.treeview();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with asp.net.  There it would simply be:

```
Form1.treeview();
```

If that is not the case, then perhaps this link may help:  [Calling method from another window (Class) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037773/calling-method-from-another-window-class-issue)

Comment: No no no no. Did you even consider the question " Do you have an instance of Form1 anywhere in form2?", and also, try to format your code sections.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways. You can pass your form to your other form.

```
public partial class TabPageEntry_Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form;
    public TabPageEntry_Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        form = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.treeview();
    }
```

You can use events:

```
public partial class TabPageEntry_Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void TreeViewHander();
    public event TreeViewHander TreeView;

    public TabPageEntry_Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView) 
        {
            TreeView();
        }
    }
```

....

```
    // Form1 
    TabPageEntry_Form2 form2 = new TabPageEntry_Form2 ();
    form2.TreeView += treeview;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to instantiate form1 and call the respective method;

```
Form1 objForm1 = new Form1();
objForm1.treeview();
```