# Bind to Property in Another Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've read up on binding to other classes but the syntax is tripping me up.

I have properties in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and I'd like to reference them `SecondWindow.xaml`.

I tried `{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.Test}}` but it complains about `Key` being null.

**Update**

Following the suggestion, I set the `SecondWindow` context to my `MainWindow` as well as tried setting the `ParentHandle`.

When the application runs, I get a bunch of runtime errors like this.

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LabelColor' property not found on 'object' ''SecondWindow' (Name='secondWindow')'. BindingExpression:Path=LabelColor;`

Comment: You should post the actual error/exception message

Comment: Check out this question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037773/calling-method-from-another-window-class-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
// I suppose MainWindow will new up an instance during some event.
var window = new SecondWindow();
window.DataContext = this; // Set to MainWindow
window.Show();
```

Then access it like this:

```
{Binding Test}
```

Comment: Ah interesting. Is it possible to have multiple data contexts so some can go to `SecondWindow` and others to `MainWindow`?

Comment: @Ternary I think you can only have one DataContext but with most controls you can set the ItemsSource and that control will ignore and DataContext from above.